# Wrong Answer in SUBSEQ spoj

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was solving Counting Subsequence Problem in spoj, but getting Wrong Answer. here is the link http://www.spoj.com/problems/SUBSEQ/

Here is my code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<cmath>
 #include<algorithm>
 int main(){
int t,n;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t-->0){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long arr[n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%ld",&arr[i]);   
    }
    long sum=arr[0];
    int start=0;
    long ans=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        while(sum>47 && start<i-1){
            sum-=arr[start];
            start++;
        }
        if(sum==47)
            ans+=1;
        if(i<n)
            sum+=arr[i];
    }
    printf("%ld\n",ans);
}
```

}

Please help me find the error ..

Comment: What is stopping you from debugging this in the usual way, e.g. adding printf statements or using a debugger ?

Comment: @PaulR I have tried all type of test case , but i'm unable to get the case where i am wrong .

Comment: This isn't C++, it's C. Not just because of all the I/O style (`printf` and `scanf` instead of streams), but because it uses variable-length arrays, which don't exist in C++. Please retag your question accordingly, or correct the code. (And fix your indentation, while you're at it).

Comment: I don't understand your logic of calculating the sum. O(N^2) solution is trivial. Just check for the sums starting at each index and check which ones equal 47 and which ones exceed it.

Comment: The `for` loop looks very wrong: `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)` - it should almost certainly be: `for(int i=1;i<n;i++)`

Comment: Did you test the simplest possible cases: `1` and `47`?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal The trivial solution will get TLE.

Comment: @molbdnilo Tested almost all possible test case including yours test case .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code will fail the following test case (at least):
`1
4
47 -47 48 -1`

Your programs gives the answer as **1**, where as the answer should be **3**, where 3 sequences as follows:

`47 -47 48 -1 [The entire sequence]`

`47 [1st element only]`

`48 -1 [3rd plus 4th elements]`

So, clearly, you've got bugs.

*PS*: BTW, why are you declaring an array of *n+1* items: `long arr[n+1];` when you are never going to reference `arr[n]`? (in fact that item won't even exist)

## [Edit]#: Adding explanation for the above use case

How about this - Its easier than you think :-)

1. Scan the numbers serially. For each number encountered, add it to sum found so far.
2. Keep a map of number of times the sum (so far) has been found.
3. Now, to make a total of 47, all we need is to find a number, which when subtracted from the sum so far should give number 47. This is required because if we subtract such number from sum found so far, it would yield 47 obtained from summation of some sequence(s) of contiguous numbers.

Take the above example, `47 -47 48 -1`

1. Initialize a map with number 0 having count = 0 (That's to say that we have found *no sum so far* exactly once - since we are at the begining)
2. Scanning the list from the beginning, take number 47, sum so far, say, s = 47. We do 2 things:

   - map(47) = 1 (since we've found sum so far = 47 for first time).
   - Now, we need to find number of times, we've can find s-47 = 0 (which is 1). So, answer so far = map(0) = 1
3. Take next number, -47. Sum so far, s = 0

   - map(0) = 1 so far, so no map(0) becomes = 2
   - We need to find number of occurrences of s-47 = -47. Which = 0. So answer so far = answer so far + 0 (remains = 1)
4. Take next number, 48, sum so far, s = 48

   - map(48) = 1
   - We need to find number of occurrences of s-48 = -1. Which = 0. So answer so far = answer so far + 0 (remains = 1)
5. Take last number, -1, sum so far, s = 47

   - map(47) = 1 (in step 2.1), so now map(47) becomes = 2
   - We need to find number of occurrences of s-47 = 0. Which = 2 (in step 3.1). So answer so far = answer so far + 2 = 3

So final answer = **3**

It should be fairly trivial to code this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But don't know how to approach with this problem. My solution will be right only for positive numbers but for negative number it wont be right , Can you tell the better way to approach this problem.

Comment: My explanation may become too long, so, I'm editing the answer